# How do I quickly drop a request in a Jetty filter?

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I've written a Jetty Filter to detect and drop requests from users that are spamming the endpoint with a flood of requests, effectively DOSing other users. What I'd really like to do once I've detected that it is a bad actor, is drop the request immediately with as little processing as possible. The best thing I have come up with so far is this:

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
if (spamRequest()) {
    response.reset();
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS_429);
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

I believe that should respond with a `429 Too Many Requests` and no body. But this is a flood of requests, and I really just want to short-circuit any processing at all and drop the connection. Throwing exceptions just causes Jetty to return a 500 with some default html response, which is no better than my current solution.

Comment: I would gladly do `response.sendRedirect("http://localhost/");`

Comment: @ErnestKiwele how is that helping? That still sends a http response.

Comment: I don't think JEE gives API-level means to deal with connection (maybe I just don't know). So yes, it doesn't help, but at least it gets rid  of the request and will force the client to waste some time. The best place to do this is a firewall, but he's looking for a quick JEE API thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using Jetty, you can use a special non-standard call ...

```java
response.sendError(-1);
```

This is essentially [`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.sendError(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError-int-) with a special "error status code" of `-1`.

*Important: The above is not compliant to the Servlet Spec and will not work outside of Jetty.*

That will abort the Http Channel and close the connection without sending a response.

Be aware, that you might see IOException's on your server logs due to the unwinding of the Servlet layers.

If you have a `RequestLog` these responses might look strange, so don't forget to at least do `response.setStatus(HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS_429)` before you call `sendError(-1)` to get something meaningful to key off of in the generated request log.

Alternatively, if you don't like this behavior, don't forget to indicate a `Connection: close` before you send a valid response to force the server to close the connection after the response.

eg:

```java
if (spamRequest()) {
    response.reset();
    response.setHeader("Connection", "close");
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS_429);
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```